# FreeFem++ code approximating the Laplace equation

Tags: numerical-methods, laplacian

I have been trying to learn FreeFem++. I have a code that shows no error. However, the code is not working.

The domain is 
$$
\Omega=[-5,5]\times[0,10].
$$

And the problem I am trying to solve is

$$
\Delta p=0\,\text{on } \Omega,
$$
$$
p=y\,\text{ if $y=10$},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial n}=0\,\text{ if }y=0, x=-5 \text{ or }x=5.
$$

Notice that the solution is $p\equiv10$.

My code reads

///////////////Code///////////////

border Gb(t=-5,5) {x=t;y=0;label=2;};//flat bottom

border Hr(t=0,10) {x=5;y=t;label=3;}; //boundary horizontal variable

border Gr(t=5,pi) {x=t;y=10;label=4;};//interface

border G(t=-pi,pi) {x=-t;y=10;label=5;};//interface

border Gl(t=-pi,-5) {x=t;y=10;label=4;};//interface

border Hl(t=0,10) {x=-5;y=10-t;label=1;};//boundary horizontal variable

func z=y;

mesh Th=buildmesh(Gl(25)+Gr(25)+G(50)+Gb(100)+Hr(200)+Hl(200));

fespace Ph(Th,P1); //impermeable BC on x

Ph p,phi;

solve Laplace(p,phi)=int2d(Th)(dx(phi)*dx(p)+dy(phi)*dy(p))-int1d(Th,Gb)(0*phi)-int1d(Th,Hr)(0*phi)-int1d(Th,Hl)(0*phi)+on(G,p=z)+on(Gr,p=z)+on(Gl,p=z); //weak formulation

plot(p,wait=1,value=true,fill=true);

/////////////End of Code/////////////

Then FreeFem++ returns the following message

-- mesh: Nb of Triangles = 37728, Nb of Vertices 19165
-- Solve : 
min 1.49772e-31 max 10
times: compile 0.186s, execution 6.051s, mpirank:0
CodeAlloc : nb ptr 2727, size :165264 mpirank: 0
Ok: Normal End

together with a plot. The problem is that the plot shows a nonconstant solution!! Any comment is very welcome.

Comment: I believe it is off-topic on this site to ask questions such as "what is the problem with my code?".

Comment: As is a math problem and a math-related code, I think that this may be the appropriate place.

In any case, do you have any suggestion on the appropriate place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you write the boundary conditions. First of all what do the pieces of the boundary with parameter $\pi$ stand for? Note that you put some boundary conditions on them also, which have nothing to do with the problem...

Since you want Neumann boundary conditions on all the sides except the upper one, you do not need to put any boundary conditions on them. The default boundary condition is the Neumann one (this is a direct consequence of the weak formulation). You only need to put the Dirichlet boundary condition on the upper side of the square which is `on(G,p=z)` (remove all other boundary conditions...). With this modification I do obtain a constant solution.